# Flutter Firebase google_sign_in This connection is not private on IOS then redirect on Google home page

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-signin

I'm new to flutter and I've struggled with the google_sign_in package on IOS.
On android, everything is working smoothly but on IOS, when I use GoogleSignIn().signIn() from google_sign_in it keeps opening a webpage for Google sign in flow. For now everything is normal.

But when I submit my email then my password, a screen with "This connection is not private..." appears.

You have 2 options. Show details button or go Back. Clicking on show details then clicking on visit this website button, is redirecting me on Google Home page and not closing the webview and I'm not logged in my app.

The only option when I'm on the google Home page is to click on Cancel to go back in my flutter app.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xle7g.png)

Below my code:

```
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
      await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final UserCredential authResult =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

Comment: Have you added reverse client id to .plist file?

Comment: @MohitKumar Thanks for your help ! 
Yes I've already did it into Info.plist file... It's working perfectly on android I really don't know why on IOS it's not

Comment: New update: The webview is closing after granting permissions if I ask for a bigger scope.
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn( scopes: [ 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly', ], );

But it's really painful for a user, and I do not need access to his contact